# Linken Sphere and Razor's Unstable Current

Tags: dota-2, dota

If **Razor** is wielding a **Linken Sphere** and a hero caster cast a targeted spell on him, will the caster still receive damage from **Unstable Current**?

Also, if it is the other way around. My hero is the one wielding the *Linken Sphere* and I casted a targeted spell on **Razor**, will I get a damage from **Unstable Current** or will *Linken Sphere* will block the damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first impression was yes, you get the damage but then I read the [Dota 2 Wiki](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Razor):

> Damage activates when the ability cast on Razor begins its effect.

and decided to do some tests.

I created a practice match with cheats enabled and used Lina and Razor to test it. I tried Laguna Blade on Razor with Linken Sphere and obviously Razor take no damage from it, but **Lina took the damage from Unstable Current**.

Comment: How about the other way around? What if Lina wields the Linken, will she get damaged from the **Unstable Current**? Or will the Linken block the damage?

Comment: Yes, Linken will block Unstable Current ([wiki](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Razor))